# Odd error message in DataFrame in a linq where clause

Tags: linq, julia

When I try to filter a `DataFrame` by a `Date` the following way:

```
@linq df |> @where(:a .> (myDate + Dates.Month(18)))
```

I get the error message:

```
LoadError: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{DataFramesMeta.SymbolParameter{T}}, ::Expr)
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor DataFramesMeta.SymbolParameter{T}(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Closest candidates are:
  call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
  convert{T}(::Type{T}, !Matched::T)
  DataFramesMeta.SymbolParameter(!Matched::Symbol)
while loading In[79], in expression starting on line 2
```

while if I define a variable `t` it works:

```
t = (myDate + Dates.Month(18))
@linq df |> @where(:a .> t)
```

Is the first case a fundamentally wrong way of using the `@where` clause? If so, why? `(myDate + Dates.Month(18))` should be just a `Date` just as `t` is, so why is this different behavior; also how to make the two cases behave the same way?

Comment: Could you post some details about your dataset, maybe do a `head(df)`.